# SelectionSort and BubbleSort - how to count number of comparisons and number swapping?

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

First of all, I have seen a similar question relating to C++, but I didn't quite understand it - plus my question is about Java.

Basically I have coded two methods that can use SelectionSort and BubbleSort on an array parsed in. While I believe I have the methods working correctly (I have run tests and they all have sorted the numbers in ascending order), I am not sure if I am counting the number of comparisons and number swaps correctly. If someone is able to test my code below and offer some feedback, I will be very grateful.

Note: I can zip up my Java project files and send them to anyone if needed.

**BubbleSort method:**

```
public String bubbleSort(int[] numbers)
    {
        System.out.println("******|Bubble Sort|******");
        StringBuilder originalArray = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 0; i <= numbers.length - 1; i++)
        {
            originalArray.append(numbers[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("Original array: " + originalArray);
        int temp; // temporary variable

        //Set boolean variable to true, 
        //to allow the first pass.
        boolean pass = true;

        int comparisons = 0;
        int swaps = 0;

        //While a pass can be made, 
        while(pass)
        {
            //Set the boolean value to false, 
            //indicating a number swap could 
            //be made.
            pass = false;

            for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++)
            {
                //increment the number of comparisons by 1.
                comparisons++;
                if(numbers[i] > numbers[i+1])
                {
                    temp = numbers[i];
                    numbers[i] = numbers[i + 1];
                    numbers[i+1] = temp;

                    //increment the amount of swaps made by 1, 
                    //to put numbers in correct order.
                    swaps++;
                    pass = true;
                }
            }
        }

        //Create a StringBuilder object - to hold 
        //the output of sorted numbers.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        //Loop through the now sorted array - appending 
        //each subsequent number in the array to the 
        //StringBuilder object.
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            sb.append(numbers[i] + " ");
        }

        //Return the final results of the sorted array.
        return "Sorted Array (asc): " + sb.toString() + "\nComparisons made: " + comparisons 
                + "\nSwaps made: " + swaps;
    }
```

**SelectionSort method**

```
public String selectionSort(int[] numbers)
    {
        System.out.println("******|Selection Sort|******");
        StringBuilder originalArray = new StringBuilder();

        int comparisons = 0;
        int swaps = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i <= numbers.length - 1; i++)
        {
            originalArray.append(numbers[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("Original array: " + originalArray);

        //Declare variable to hold first element
        int first;

        //declare temporary variable, to be used in 
        //swapping integers.
        int temp;

        for(int x = numbers.length - 1; x > 0; x--)
        {
            first = 0;
            comparisons++;
            for(int y = 1; y <= x; y++)
            {
                //comparisons++;
                if(numbers[y] > numbers[first])
                {
                    first = y;
                    //comparisons++;
                    swaps++;
                }
                temp = numbers[first];
                numbers[first] = numbers[x];
                numbers[x] = temp;
                //swaps++;
            }
        }

        //Create a StringBuilder object - to hold 
        //the output of sorted numbers.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        //Loop through the now sorted array - appending 
        //each subsequent number in the array to the 
        //StringBuilder object.
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            sb.append(numbers[i] + " ");
        }

        //Return the final results of the sorted array.
        return "Sorted Array (asc): " + sb.toString() + "\nComparisons made: " + comparisons 
                + "\nSwaps made: " + swaps;
    }
```

Comment: Seems correct in Bubble sort. But not in Selection sort. Use the 1st commented increment for both `swaps` and `comparisons`. Ah Well, swapping itself seems to be at wrong place, in selection sort.

Comment: seems to be correct except, you should put 'comparisons' in inner for loop for SelectionSort

Comment: could u please make it more clear. are you intention is to find out the number of swapping/comparison done during the sorting process. or you to find out the error/bug in you sorting code ?

Comment: Rob, could you explain what you find difficult with this? It's just that to me this seems straightforward. Is it that you don't understand the concepts of "swap" and "comparison", or that you are unsure of how the control structures ("if" and so on) work? (I'm not trying to be annoying, but I teach stuff like this, and it would be good to know what difficulties my students might face.)

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy Sometimes I still get confused with the double for loop, even though I have programmed since 2009. A double if loop is easy enough to understand though. It has been a while since I have looked over algorithms etc - I am pretty much refreshing myself at the moment as I haven't actively coded in Java since 2011.

Comment: @RameshKarn I am wanting to find the number of swapping and comparisons done. This is the only part of the program I can see that I am having trouble with.

Comment: I am off to bed now, have an 8am start NZST - I will answer any questions during my morning break tomorrow :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For BUBBLE SORT:

*Key comparisons ->* **(n*(n-1))/2**

*Item assignments (swaps)  ->* **3*(n-1)**

For SELECTION SORT:

*Key comparisons ->* **(n*(n-1))/2** (same as bubble)

*Item assignments (swaps)  ->* **(n*(n-1))/4**

(Note that **n** is the number of your array size)